# lxml: Undefined variable etree

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, lxml

I'm returning to Python after a little hiatus. Some projects that used to work now have a problem with lxml.

I have the [latest source from github](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/) installed locally and have it in an Eclipse project.

This project has the following in PyDev-PYTHONPATH:
/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}
/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/src

In a project that uses `lxml`, in the Project References, I have the lxml project checked.
A file in this project has:

```
import lxml
```

which is underlined in yellow with the warning:
*Unused import: lxml*

For this line:

```
from lxml import etree
```

it gives the error:
*Unresolved import etree*

A line like so:

```
kml = etree.Element("kml", nsmap = namespaces)
```

has the error: *Undefined variable etree*

This project also has the following in PyDev-PYTHONPATH:
/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}
/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/src

I've read this question, but I don't see an answer there:
[Python 2.7 on Google App Engine, cannot use lxml.etree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130554/python-2-7-on-google-app-engine-cannot-use-lxml-etree)

On a Windows 10, 64 bit machine. This was not a problem on the same machine with Windows 7. Not sure if that is the problem. Wouldn't think so.

I found the value for PYTHONPATH in the Run Configuration. It has lxml:

```
D:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.9.2.201502050007\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\StateDivision;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\StateDivision\src;
C:\Python27\podbc64;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\lxml;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\lxml\src;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\XlsxWriter;
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\DLLs;
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib;
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3;
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\site-packages;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcToolBox\Scripts
```

Cleaned up the project, switched to Python 3.5, PYTHONPATH now looks like this:

```
D:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.9.2.201502050007\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\StateDivision;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\StateDivision\src;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\lxml;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\lxml\src;
D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\lxml\src\lxml;
C:\Python35-32\DLLs;
C:\Python35-32\lib;
C:\Python35-32;C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages
```

Still get same error with etree.

Edit:

Answer is to not use source (use python .exe installer for windows) and use `from lxml import etree`, not `import lxml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not import the `etree` module as a global name in your module, only the `lxml` package itself. You need to import the `etree` module from the `lxml` package:

```
from lxml import etree
```

See the [`lxml.etree` tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).

If `import lxml` works but `from lxml import etree` fails, you either have another `lxml.py` file in your path that masks the package, *or* you are trying to use a uncompiled source distribution. Use:

```
import lxml
print(lxml.__file__)
```

to find and rename the offending file.

- If it points to `lxml.py` remove or rename that file.
- If it points to `<PATH>/src/lxml/__init__.py` you are trying to use an *uncompiled source distribution*. You'll have to compile the Python extension code, or find a binary distribution for your platform to install.

Comment: @AlLelopath: you have a *different module named `lxml`* in your path.

Comment: By "path" do you mean PATH or PYTHONPATH? If I look in the system environment variables, there is no PYTHONPATH defined. Also, PATH, does not have any python references.

Comment: @AlLelopath: The Python module search path (which includes the current local working directory). There is a *standard* module search path set by Python.

Comment: The print statement you suggest shows this: *D:\My Documents\eclipse\workspace2\lxml\src\lxml\__init__.pyc*, which is the location of the project I mention in the question.

Comment: @AlLelopath: so is your script working or is this just Eclipse misunderstanding a Python import?

Comment: The script is not working because of the error with `etree`. It works up until  that point, but crashes with it hits `kml = etree.Element("kml", nsmap = namespaces) ` with *NameError: global name etree is not defined*

Comment: I found that PYTHONPATH has lxml in it. See above.

Comment: @AlLelopath: how did you install `lxml`? A `src` directory looks like you have the source distribution, not a compiled binary for Windows.

Comment: Yes, as stated at the top of the question, I have the latest source from github installed locally and have it in an Eclipse project.

Comment: @AlLelopath: you can't just use the source distribution. lxml contains a compiled Python extension; you'll need to compile it yourself (a rather involved task on Windows) or find a binary distribution to install.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sorry for bashing a dead cow, but I'm in the same predicament. Difference is I'm on a Debian (stretch) machine and I installed lxml from package (apt-get install python3-lxml). In my case "print(lxml.__file__)" gives: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.py"; in the same dir I see etree.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so and objectify.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so, so I assume I have the binaries. What's wrong? I already tried uninstalling/reinstalling, what else? TiA

Comment: @ZioByte: hard to diagnose. Are all dependencies of the `.so` files available (`ldd path/to/file.so`)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yup. all libs are there (it took some time to resolve all links). Any other idea? Should I try installing via pip?

Comment: @ZioByte: the two remaining issues are that you are using the wrong Python binary for those extensions (e.g. not Python 3.5, but added that directory to your `sys.path` in another version), or you have a local `lxml.py` or similar for the script where you see the error. Either way, please post a new question with as much detail as you can, including pointing to this question and explaining how you already tested for the cases described here.